# Extracting the parent folder of a file using batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, command-line, scripting

I would like to extract the parent folder of a file (ex new.log) using batch scripting. Can anyone please help me with this. I have the following command to find the complete path of the file but I just need the path up-to the parent folder excluding the file name.

```
dir /s/b new.log

the output for the above commmand is:

C:\my_test_dir\trying_stuff_out\new.log
```

I need to extract the parent folder path of the file **"new.log"** so the output should be **"C:\my_test_dir\trying_stuff_out"** or **"C:\my_test_dir\trying_stuff_out\"**

And I would like to extend it by using the same for printing out the parent folders of multiple files of the same type using a for loop E x:

```
dir /s/b *.log
```

Comment: `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("new.log") do echo "%%~dpa"`  -?

Comment: You were pretty close using the `for-loop` tag.  You could have taken it one step further and read the help for the `FOR` command and you would see the command modifiers that you can use with the `FOR` variable.